# Вычисление параметров прибыли и убытков

Tags: python

Есть система вычислений, которая, зная `base_price_wo_vat` (эта часть всегда имеет одно и то же значение), запрашивая `retro_otn` (процент ретро бонуса, пишется как 0.4? например) и `price_shelf` (цену на полке), вычисляет в конечном итоге `total_margin_otn` и попутно еще часть промежуточных параметров.

Вопрос: как, зная эти отношения параметров, сделать так, чтобы программа могла еще вычислить `price_shelf`, если известны `front_margin_otn`,
`base_price_wo_vat` (он неизменен) и `retro_otn`?

```
base_price_wo_vat = 438.89
base_price = base_price_wo_vat * 1.2
retro_otn = float(input('Введите суммарный ретро бонус без учета ЖЦ '))
retro_abs = base_price_wo_vat * retro_otn
price_shelf = float(input('Введите необходимую цену на полке '))
front_margin_abs = price_shelf - base_price
front_margin_otn = front_margin_abs / base_price
total_margin_abs = retro_abs + front_margin_abs
total_margin_otn = total_margin_abs / price_shelf
print('Общая маржа клиента равна', (round(total_margin_otn, 2))*100, '% ')
print('Фронт маржа клиента равна', (round(front_margin_otn, 1))*100, '% ', 'при бэке в ', (round(retro_otn, 2))*100, '% ', 'от товарооборота без НДС')
```

Comment: Ну пройдитесь по формулам, вроде можно тут в обратную сторону формулы посчитать. Правда, не очень понимаю, как это относится к питону, это чисто математика.

Comment: Я только только начал изучать питон, подумал может есть какая-то суперфункция, которая позволяет не описывать всё формулами)) А на основании одного алгоритма интерпретатор понимает как искать из него отдельные переменные)) Я верил в чудо)

Comment: Ну для формул есть Wolfram Alpha, в Питоне тоже есть Sympy или как его, но там нужны сами формулы, а не код программы )

Comment: Так то если вы дадите много данных, посчитанных таким образом, можно применить метод регрессии и попытаться вычислить формулу через машинное обучение ))